# Issue in changing the dataframe schema from int to double

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe label and i want to change the schema of the dataframe from integer to double

The schema of the data frame is

`label.printSchema`

`root
 |-- value: integer (nullable = false)`

the command I am using is

`label = label.withColumn('value', label.value.cast('double'))`

the error i am receiving is:

`error: unclosed character literal`

Comment: sparql != spark

Comment: did u import from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

Comment: i did and it is not taking place i just want to change the schema of existing dataframe from int to double , please tell me how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

label = label.withColumn("value", label("value").cast(DoubleType))

Answer (score -1):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType,IntegerType
cSchema = StructType([StructField("value",IntegerType())])
test_list = [[1],[2]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(test_list,schema=cSchema) 
df.printSchema()
castedDF = df.withColumn("value", df["value"].cast("double"))
castedDF.printSchema()
castedDF.show()
```

And, the output is (as expected)

```
root
 |-- value: integer (nullable = true)
root
 |-- value: double (nullable = true)
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|  1.0|
|  2.0|
+-----+
```